# Image not showing in accordion

Tags: html

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bx5kQ.png)My image wont show within the accordion line. Wondering how to fix this?

```html
 <div class="accordion-item">
        <button id="accordion-button-2" aria-expanded="false"><span class="accordion-title">What do these icons
            mean? <img src="/Untitled.png" alt="Untitled"></span><span class="icon" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
        <div class="accordion-content">
          <p>They show you how many items have been offered for the pictured item. For example this item has had 7 items
            offered. It is up to the items owner to decide which item to accept.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you please add your folder structure to your question?

Comment: Have you tried `font-awesome` icons ? instead of image you can use "untitled" icons or related to it here i found one `<i class="fa fa-folder" aria-hidden="true"></i>
`
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is most likely that your image is not in the position you mentioned in the src attribute.

I would recommend you to take a look at how the HTML file paths work. Iäll provide you with a link: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp